# EmailAuthor - Add attachments on record

Tags: javascript, email, attachment, apex-email-service

I've created a custom "send an email" button with a URL hack as follow:
`/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid={!RMA__c.Id}&retURL={!RMA__c.Link}&p2_lkid={!RMA__c.ContactID__c}&template_id=00X50000001oz0c`.

Now - I would like to add all the attachments on the record to the opened letter, is it possible via URL hack? javascript? or maybe even apex class (I dont want to use single email)?

example to clarify: User clicks the custom send an email on the contact record and the EmailAuthor screen opens, now he wants all the attachments on that contact record automatically be added to this email.

Comment: Short answer is No. By URL you can not achieve this.

Comment: Can I do an apex class then, but still enable the user to change the email before sending (like in the 'send an email' page)?

Comment: You can do it by Apex but with hard limitation. You will have to work within 6MB heap size. With attachment this will be difficult.